# Не срабатывает обычное добавление элемента в множество

Tags: python, рекурсия, множества

Разбираюсь в учебном примере, но не догоняю в чем дело (((

Есть функция `get_child`

```
import random

def get_child(node):
    return random.randint(0, node)
```

с помощью неё рекурсивно наполняем множество

```
   def tree(parent):
    child = get_child(parent)
    if child == 0:
        return {child}
    else:
        full_tree = tree(child)
        return full_tree.union({parent})
```

например выводим `print(tree(700))`, все работает.

Но если использовать более напрашивающийся `full_tree.add(parent)` вместо `full_tree.union({parent})`, то будет выходить ошибка. Чем код снизу так плох в сравнении с кодом выше ?

```
def tree(parent):
    child = get_child(parent)
    if child == 0:
        return {child}
    else:
        full_tree = tree(child)
        return full_tree.add(parent)
```

Ошибка: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто метод `add` ничего не возвращает, в отличие от `union`.

Замените:

```
    return full_tree.add(parent)
```

На:

```
    full_tree.add(parent)
    return full_tree
```

Ругаться уже не будет. Но правильность работы алгоритма в целом я не проверял.

Comment: Да, вы правы ! Я упустил, что `add` ничего не возвращает. Спасибо !